# ec2, pyspark: java.net.UnknownHostException Name or service not known

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pyspark, unknown-host

I have set up the pyspark environment on AWS ec2 instance following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@josemarcialportilla/getting-spark-python-and-jupyter-notebook-running-on-amazon-ec2-dec599e1c297)

However, when I simply test

```
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
```

it keeps giving the error as follow:

[image: error msg]

I use 54.255.207.212 to connect my ec2, and after log in, the ip-address for this ec2 is 172.30.0.112.

Is there anything wrong about the configuration or the hostname?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Share your security group configurations. I think that's where issue resides in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under your security group configuration, allow all inbound traffic to the instance.

[image]

Comment: Its rather safe and secure to have specific port open to all, or "All Traffic" to all to specific security groups.

Comment: @Rumesh Eranga it works!!! I have surveyed some document about VPC and finally know what's wrong. Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: @Vineeth thanks for remainder! I have configured the inbound connection to certain users concerning the safety issue.

Comment: @陳嘉茹 if it helps, an upvote would send us some love :)